# How far can I wire a Sensor or an electrical component that it would work?

Tags: voltage, sensor, analog, distance

I had this doubt in my mind. I wanted to know the range till which a sensor could be attached so that it works. Suppose I have a setup, in which my main circuit is in a room and I have a PIR sensor or a fingerprint scanner near the door. Will it work at a distance of say 20-30m from the room? I am asking this because there will be a voltage drop due to the wire. If suppose it doesn't, how can I make it work? Do I need to provide extra voltage externally? I'll  be using an Arduino.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is the sensor analog or digital?

Comment: Depends on the type of wire/cable and the type/magnitude of the signal.

Comment: Please add details - but, in general you'll have trouble putting that much distance between the sensor and the Arduino. It would be better to place the Arduino near the sensor and transmit the signal elsewhere - a standard Cat 5e cable is reliable to about 100 meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to test the setup using your specific sensors. To find out the exact voltage drop, you may measure the resistance of your wire.

Moving on to your PIR sensor; due to long length of the wire, it may get triggered at random. You can use a pull up resistor (say, 4.7K or lower) on the signal pin.

Fingerprint sensors use serial interface. RS485 protocol can help you achieve long range communication without loss of data.